# No 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' ServletContext attribute - Glassfish 4.1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket, glassfish, containers

I'm using Glassfish 4.1 to deploy my WAR application. Cannot connect to websocket, getting this message from glassfish:

My websocket configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(socketHandler(),"/socket");;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler socketHandler() {
        return new WebSocketEndpoint();
    }


}
```

WebSocket Handler

```
public class WebSocketEndpoint extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) {
        System.out.println("Testing "+message.getPayload());
        try {
            session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(testService.getWelcomeMessage()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I got a bean in my dispatcher-servlet

```
<bean class="pl.iaserver.websocket.WebSocketConfig"/>
```

The error:

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' ServletContext attribute. Are you running in a Servlet container that supports JSR-356?
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy.getContainer(AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy.getSupportedExtensions(AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.DefaultHandshakeHandler.doHandshake(DefaultHandshakeHandler.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have Glassfish Tyrus of 1.8 version only. Put it in the modules folder of GlassFish (glassfish/modules).

- tyrus-core-1.8.jar
- tyrus-client-1.8.jar
- tyrus-container-glassfish-cdi-1.8.jar
- tyrus-container-glassfish-ejb-1.8.jar
- tyrus-container-grizzly-client-1.8.jar
- tyrus-container-servlet-1.8.jar
- tyrus-server-1.8.jar
- tyrus-spi-1.8.jar

You can find them on the http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.tyrus.

The reason for this is because Spring WebSocket version 4.2.1 (I have
this version) depends on GlassFish Tyrus version 1.8.

Be sure to put these files in the modules folder (glassfish/modules) instead of the files tyrus lying there, otherwise Default Tyrus will be loaded.

Comment: I put those files in my war by adding `org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-client:1.13.1` dependency to my runtime configuration. That cut it too.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add the javax.websocket dependency.

Maven:

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
     <version>1.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
'javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:1.1'
```

See: https://tyrus.java.net/dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

What I found to work was including the following dependencies in your POM file (I originally got the information from [here](https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-build-java-websocket-applications-using-the-jsr-356-api/)):

```
<!-- add the dependency for JSR 356 API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- add Tyrus JSR 356 implementation related dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>

<!-- add the tyrus-container-grizzly dependency to our pom.xml. 
This will provide a standalone container to deploy WebSocket
applications -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-container-grizzly</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently while running  my spring-boot application in tomcat 9 (> version 9.0.8). 
It is a regression introduced in the latest version of tomcat : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15746