# Tomcat + Spring Boot + 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket, tomcat8.5

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot (2.0.5) web application (war) with web sockets to a Tomcat 8.5.37 server, it previously worked with Tomcat 7. My web socket configuration is throwing the exception and preventing the application from starting. Am I missing some type of configuration in Spring or Tomcat? Something that is no longer available since I upgraded Tomcat?

I am able to run locally (through eclipse and eclipse's Tomcat v8.5), but when I try to deploy to our Tomcat server on our qa enviroment I get the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'createWebSocketContainer' defined in class path resource [com/soft/core/app/configuration/WebSocketConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attribute 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' not found in ServletContext
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:740)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5267)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attribute 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' not found in ServletContext
```

I was able to isolate to cause to this bean, if I remove this bean the app starts up:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{
...
...
    @Bean
    public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
        ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
        container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(1024 * 1024); // 1 MB
        return container;
    }
}
```

This is my Spring-BOM.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is my pom.xml

```
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   ...
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>              
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        
</dependencies>
```

Comment: The error implies that your servlet container is not enabled for web sockets. Do the web sockets work without `ServletServerContainerFactoryBean` problematic bean?

Comment: [different server but may be related...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074948/no-javax-websocket-server-servercontainer-servletcontext-attribute-glassfish)

Comment: The web sockets work without the `ServletServerContainerFactoryBean`, but I need to set a larger max text message buffer.

Comment: You're trying to deploy a standalone executable jar with an embedded Tomcat, right? That's what your pom seems to be implying at least.

Comment: I am deploying a war. I will update my question.

Comment: What do you mean "I'm able to run locally"? If you take a fresh local install of Tomcat 8.5 and deploy the WAR locally will it work?

Comment: When I say run locally I mean through eclipse, which is also using Tomcat 8.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many years, we were finally able to resolve this issue by updating to the latest minor version of Apache Tomcat 8 (`8.5.78`).

This is an alternative option to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54116592/1289016) of downgrading to an unstable Apache Tomcat 8 version.

Answer (score 5):

Had same issue for `Tomcat 9.0.20` and `Tomcat 9.0.21` with `SpringBoot 2.1.1` to `SpringBoot 2.1.6`.
Found some discussion here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15746

They seems found problem with some kind `tomcat version`. Anyway.

What helped me was to add `web.xml` to catalog `WEB-INF` and paste following snippet:

```
<absolute-ordering>
    <name>spring_web</name>
</absolute-ordering>
```

Spring documentation: [WebSocket and Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-deployment)

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for me too (Tomcat+Spring+GraphQL application)

Comment: Just for reference: I created the `web.xml` file containing the snippet above in `src/main/webapp`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best answer, but I was able to fix this issue by using `Apache Tomcat 8.5.4` which does not seem to be stable. I am unsure on WHY this fixes these issues, but my best guess is something to do with the `Tomcat\lib` libraries.

I am using `Java 8`, which Apache says to use `Tomcat9`, but I received the same exception using that version as well.

Comment: got the same issue with my tomcat server (running on ubuntu 18.04), there was an urgent update (auto) and my tomcat got updated to `8.5.39`... now after restarting my tomcat service... my application won't start and got the same issue as yours. I tried version `8.5.40` with no luck. I will try `8.5.4` and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue as well and inserting the following snippet into my `web.xml` file did not work for me:

```
<absolute-ordering>
    <name>spring_web</name>
</absolute-ordering>
```

However, I did fix it by downloading the most recent `Apache Tomcat` (went from `9.0.30` to `9.0.34`).